# mysql match urls

Tags: mysql, url, match

I am inserting urls in a mysql table. For example i have inserted 8 entries as below:

```
 url
-----------------------------
http://example.com 
http://www.example.com 
http://example.com/ 
http://www.example.com/
http://example.com/sports 
http://www.example.com/sports 
http://example.com/sports/ 
http://www.example.com/sports/
```

. Now how can i write a query to match example.com which should return the first 4 entries since they are the same url? Similarly how do i write a query to get the last 4 entries as they are the same? Even if i have huge number of entries the query should be fast is it possible ??

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you have those links in a single table, you could get them like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE url LIKE '%example.com%'
```

Is this fast? NO - it will require full table scan.

If I were you, I would model my DB to hold those URLs in 2 tables:

**links**

- *id*
- *base_url* - holds example.com

**related_links**

- *id*
- *link_id* - FK on links
- *subdomain* - holds www.
- *relative_url* - holds /sports/

**Edit** - to answer comment:

Your DB is not normalized right now. You hold multiple records for "the same thing" - you are not benefitting the advantages of DBs. DBs are useful when working with structured data - your query needs to make string operations - an pretty complex ones. So, while it would probably be possible to return the results you need and want with the current form of the DB, it won't be a trivial task, and definitely performance would suck.

My recommendation - modify the DB - at least add the columns `subdomain` and `relative_path` to your table and hold this information as separate as possible - to be able to make aggregated queries on it.

Comment: If i do the above query it will return all the 8 entries that are there in the table. I just want it to return the first 4 as they are the same url. I cant use 2 diff tables as i need to store in the same table and i have to match a number of links in a file which have their full urls and not base url, subdomain ,relative url.

Comment: I edited my answer to address your last worries - I believe it's not what you wanted to hear - but is the way to go :)

Comment: This wont work for me as i need to store all unique urls. Is there a way to find out if a url requires a trialing slash like say if u enter example.com the browser adds http:// and the last / so it will be http://example.com/ Also if my url is http://example.com/index.html it should not add the last slash here. Is there a way to do so in php?? When to know i can add last slash and when i cant?

Comment: @peter: You can still store unique urls and have more columns (that you use for searching).